# /etc/aliases using pipe to run script return error (mailer=prog, dsn=5.3.0, stat=unknown mailer error 2)

Tags: email, pipe, sendmail, aliases

I would like to get any advice for my issue to run script on /etc/aliases.
At first, here are my envirements/script.

- OS : centos 6
- script : python 2.6.6
- mail : sendmail-8.14 / dovecot-2x
- python script (it's very simple for testing)

> import sys
>
> f = open("aa.txt", 'w')
>
> for i in range(1, 5): 
>       data = "%d \n" % i 
>       f.write(data)
>
> f.close()
>   sys.exit()

and then I did some congiguration to use smrsh like, make link on /etc/smrsh/, move script on /etc/smrsh/...

and then modified the /etc/aliases as below:

```
testuser:  "|/etc/smrsh/python /etc/smrsh/aa.py"
```

and then run `newaliases`.

When I send email to testuser user, maillog shows error as below: 
(sorry for changing some info like IP, domain)

```
Mar 13 11:14:38 localhost sendmail[8153]: s2DBEcX7008153: from=<ttt@test.com>, size=4448, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<B75C8C1216C9824DBF46410575577E294559AC17@test.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=relay.test.com [xx.xxx.000.xx]
Mar 13 11:14:39 localhost sendmail[8154]: s2DBEcX7008153: to="|/etc/smrsh/python /etc/smrsh/aa.py", ctladdr=<testuser@[xx.xx.xx.xx]> (8/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=prog, pri=34652, dsn=5.3.0, stat=unknown mailer error 1
Mar 13 11:14:39 localhost sendmail[8154]: s2DBEcX7008153: s2DBEdX7008154: DSN: unknown mailer error 1
```

but, just forwarding email via /etc/aliases works very well like, 
testuser : test@zzz.com

I tried to run with smrsh on the shell :

> > smrsh -c "|/etc/smrsh/python /etc/smrsh/aa.py"

it also works very well.

here are my sendmail.cf for Mprog,

```
Mlocal,         P=/usr/bin/procmail, F=lsDFMAw5:/|@qSPfhn9, S=EnvFromL/HdrFromL, R=EnvToL/HdrToL,
                T=DNS/RFC822/X-Unix,
                A=procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u
Mprog,          P=/usr/sbin/smrsh, F=lsDFMoqeu9, S=EnvFromL/HdrFromL, R=EnvToL/HdrToL, D=$z:/,
                T=X-Unix/X-Unix/X-Unix,
                A=smrsh -c $u
```

and, /etc/smrsh/

```
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   17 Mar 13 09:01 procmail -> /usr/bin/procmail
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   15 Mar 13 09:08 python -> /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   15 Mar 13 09:42 smrsh -> /usr/sbin/smrsh
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   17 Feb 13 09:17 vacation -> /usr/bin/vacation
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  125 Mar 13 11:27 aa.py
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   12 Mar 13 11:27 aa.txt
```

Could someone help to slove this problem? 
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Sendmail FAQ 4.13 : What does "unknown mailer error 1" mean?](http://web.fis.unico.it/public/faqs/mail/sendmail/section4.html#4.13)

Sendmail expects exit code zero (0) to signal all "OK" **OR** exit codes from 64 to 78 to signal specific problems.  In your case the exit code (1) is not on the list of exit codes sendmail can interpret.

Valid exit codes to signal errors/problems are listed in [`sysexits.h`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%204.3-RELEASE&format=html)

```
#define EX_USAGE        64      /* command line usage error */
#define EX_DATAERR      65      /* data format error */
#define EX_NOINPUT      66      /* cannot open input */
#define EX_NOUSER       67      /* addressee unknown */
#define EX_NOHOST       68      /* host name unknown */
#define EX_UNAVAILABLE  69      /* service unavailable */
#define EX_SOFTWARE     70      /* internal software error */
#define EX_OSERR        71      /* system error (e.g., can't fork) */
#define EX_OSFILE       72      /* critical OS file missing */
#define EX_CANTCREAT    73      /* can't create (user) output file */
#define EX_IOERR        74      /* input/output error */
#define EX_TEMPFAIL     75      /* temp failure; user is invited to retry */
#define EX_PROTOCOL     76      /* remote error in protocol */
#define EX_NOPERM       77      /* permission denied */
#define EX_CONFIG       78      /* configuration error */
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of error in the script.
I solved the same problem just by trying to launch the script with full path.

```
user@linuxMachine:$ /etc/smrsh/aa.py
```

There might be for example errors associated with related paths in your code if you work with files.

Comment: Before that I had the 126 error, and I solved it by script rights delegating.